# How do you search for all documents that have a specific embedded document in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Currently I use the following to search an individual document to see if a specific embedded document exists:

```
User.where(first_name:"Josh").first.attributes['address'].nil?
```

How do I search the entire User collection for documents that have the 'address' embedded document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
User.where(:address.exists => true)
```